# Is it possible to customize Jitsi default meeting /Live Stream UI

Tags: flutter, jitsi

I'm planning to use Jitsi for my Flutter application for the live streaming. https://jitsi.org/jitsi-meet/

1. Is it possible to customize Jitsi default meeting /Live Stream UI in our own mobile Application?
2. Can we directly live stream via Jitsi without Youtube?
3. What are some recommendations (open source softwares/SDK ) for a live stream application similar to Facebook live stream?

Answer (score 2):

- Considering you're talking about Jitsi (with an 's') instead of Jitzi*

1. Yes, it is possible, its UI is written on react. You can clone their repository and can change the UI as you like and then you can then recompile it. They have given very good instructional steps to recompile.
2. Yes.
3. You can try Openvidu, its written natively for Android, iOS and web using WebRTC (Jitsi is written on WebRTC too). It even provides capability to broadcast/stream and IP camera protocols.

Comment: thank you for your prompt answers. for the second question, I didn't find a way to do that without passing the youtube live stream key. >>>> https://jitsi.org/blog/live-streaming-with-jitsi-and-youtube/<<<< this is the documentation I referred. do you have any tutorials or documentation of how to do stream without youtube?

Comment: Hello any one have an idea where to find the instructions about recompiling